# Find the derivative of $f(\beta) = (\vec{y} -X\beta)^T(\vec{y} -X\beta)$ using the product rule

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, least-squares

So I want to differentiate $f(\beta) = (\vec{y} -X\beta)^T(\vec{y} -X\beta)$ using the product rule. Here:

- $\vec{y}$ is an $n \times 1$ vector
- $X$ is an $ n \times p$ matrix
- $\beta$ is a $p \times 1$ vector

In particular, say I just want to expand the original expression like this: $$f(\beta) = (\vec{y} -X\beta)^T(\vec{y} -X\beta) = (\vec{y}^T -\beta^TX^T)(\vec{y} -X\beta).$$

Then, I want to just apply the product rule $$\frac{\mathrm{d}f(\beta)}{\mathrm{d}\beta} =-X^T(\vec{y} -X\beta) - (\vec{y}^T -\beta^TX^T)X = $$
$$ = -X^T\vec{y} + X^TX\beta-\vec{y}^TX+\beta^TX^TX =$$
$$= -X^T\vec{y}+X^TX\beta-(X^T\vec{y})^T + (X^TX\beta)^T.$$

But this doesn't work because the first two terms have dimensions $p \times 1$, while the last two have dimensions $1 \times p$. I know I should be able to combine the terms, so what exactly goes wrong in a derivation like this.

Note that I don't want to expand the original expression further and then take the derivative; I've seen it done that way, but I really want to figure out why this doesn't work, i.e. what rule I'm missing. Also, I know I could just use the chain rule and the fact that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^T x = 2x^T,$$
but I still want to figure out why the product rule doesn't work in the naive way I wanted to do it above.

edit: Hmm, is it because the derivative is a function that acts on a vector in this case? So that if we call that vector $\vec{z}$, we would get

$$f'(\beta) \vec{z} = -(X\vec{z})^T(\vec{y} -X\beta) - (\vec{y}^T -\beta^TX^T)(X \vec{z}) = $$
$$ = -\vec{z}^TX^T\vec{y}+\vec{z}^TX^TX\beta-\vec{y}^TX\vec{z} + \beta^TX^TX\vec{z}.$$

But then because these are scalar quantities, we have

$$-\vec{z}^TX^T\vec{y} = (-\vec{z}^TX^T\vec{y})^T = -\vec{y}^TX\vec{z} \text{, and}$$
$$ \vec{z}X^TX\beta = (\vec{z}^TX^TX\beta)^T = \beta^TX^TX\vec{z}.$$

So what I wrote above would be perfectly correct, it's just that I could simplify it further this way by taking into account what the derivative is and how it acts?

Comment: One way to make this clear is to use coordinates, $\frac d{d\beta_i}$. Then make sure that vectors have indices downstairs and covectors having indices upstairs. Use Kronecker delta to raise and lower indices. Then you will find everything will work out.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a scalar function of two real vectors and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= a^Tc \,\,= c^Ta \cr
df &= a^Tdc + c^Tda \cr
}$$
Now suppose you're told that $c$ is actually a function of $a$, i.e. $\,c=a.$

That's easy enough to handle.
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2a^Tda\cr
}$$
Now suppose you're told that $a$ itself is a function of $\beta$, i.e. $\,a=(X\beta-y)$

Again, this doesn't change things too much. 
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2a^TX\,d\beta \cr
}$$
Now let's collect terms into a single vector $\,g=2X^Ta,\,$
substitute it into the expression, and isolate the *gradient* vector.
$$\eqalign{
df &= g^Td\beta \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\beta} &= g = 2X^T(X\beta-y) \cr\cr
}$$
The problem with your approach is that it assumes the existence of a rule 
$$
\frac{\partial(a^Tc)}{\partial\beta} = 
\Big(\frac{\partial a}{\partial\beta}\Big)^Tc + 
a^T\Big(\frac{\partial c}{\partial\beta}\Big) 
$$
which turns out to be **false**.

The correct rule is
$$
\frac{\partial(a^Tc)}{\partial\beta} = 
\Big(\frac{\partial a}{\partial\beta}\Big)^Tc + 
\Big(\frac{\partial c}{\partial\beta}\Big)^Ta 
$$
or the transpose of this, depending on your preferred layout convention.

Comment: Do you have a source on that last rule you stated? I namely didn't see this in any resource on matrix calculus that I looked up.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the problem, let's use a simple function.
$$\phi = x^TAx$$
Take its differential.
$$d\phi = x^TAdx + dx^TAx$$
Transpose the 2nd term so we can factor out the $dx$.
$$d\phi = x^TAdx + x^TA^Tdx = (x^TA + x^TA^T)\,dx $$
Collect terms into a single vector $g=(Ax+A^Tx)$ and write this as.
$$d\phi = g^Tdx$$
Therefore $g^T$ is the *gradient* of this function.

Now let's attack the problem as you proposed. Proceeding rather loosely we get
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 = x^TA\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}
 + \frac{\partial x^T}{\partial x}Ax
$$
Once again, you need to "transpose" that 2nd term in order to factor the expression.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= x^TA\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}
 + x^TA^T\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} \cr
 &= \Big(x^TA + x^TA^T\Big)\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} \cr
 &= x^TA + x^TA^T \cr
}$$
The reason I quoted the word *transpose* is because
$$\frac{\partial x^T}{\partial x}\ne\bigg(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\bigg)^T$$
In fact, the term on the RHS is the identity matrix which equals its transpose (i.e. $I^T=I$), while the term on the LHS **does not exist** $-$ and this is the fatal flaw of your method.

Comment: In the third line where you say "Transpose the 2nd term...", why are we able to do this?

Comment: Because the **_transpose_** does not change the scalar product of two (real) vectors, i.e.  $a^Tb=b^Ta.\,$ Or more generally $a^TMb=(Mb)^Ta=b^TM^Ta\,$ where $M$ is an arbitrary matrix.